# $\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(-n^2)}{1-4n^2}$ in closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, closed-form

I have accrossed this sum which is defined as :$\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\exp(-n^2)}{1-4n^2}$ , [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(+e%5E(-n%C2%B2)%2F(1-4n%C2%B2)),+n%3D-infty+to+infty) assume that series is converges and gives $\approx 0.75229789\cdots$ , really I have tried to present that value in closed form using [Inverse symbolic calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=0.752297898472243144&lookup_type=simple) but i didn't succeeded , Now my  question is :  to give the value of the titled series in the closed form ?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that this has a decent closed form? What do you mean by "integral representation"?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: Most likely this will be related to the integral/derivatives of theta functions: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html
(if that counts as a closed form)

Comment: @robjohn: there is a nice closed form. This is a problem recently proposed by Cornel Ioan Valean.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: That is nice. That should have been included in the question for context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT 02.05.21**

Inspired by a recent comment of @stocha I have found a simpler derivation of the final result, without having to consider jumps in the antiderivative.

From $(d7)$ and $(1)$ we have

$$s := \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-n^2}}{1-4n^2}= \sqrt{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} | \sin(x)|\,dx\tag{e1}$$

Now we break up the integration range into intervals from $ \pi k$ to $\pi(k+1)$, $k=0,1,2,...$. This serves to remove the absolute value function from the $\sin$ and we get

$$\begin{align}\frac{s}{\sqrt{\pi}} 
&=  ​\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-x^2}  \sin(x)\,dx - \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} e^{-x^2} \sin(x)\,dx\\
+& \int_{2\pi}^{3\pi} e^{-x^2}  \sin(x)\,dx - \int_{3\pi}^{4\pi} e^{-x^2} \sin(x)\,dx + ...\\
=& \sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k \int_{\pi k}^{\pi(k+1)}  e^{-x^2}  \sin(x)\,dx\end{align}\tag{e2}$$

Now

$$\int e^{-x^2}  \sin(x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4 e^{\frac{1}{4}}}\left(\text{erfi}(\frac{1}{2}+ i x)+ \text{erfi}(\frac{1}{2}- i x) \right)\tag{e3}$$

where $\text{erfi}(z)= - i \text{erf}(i z)$ and $\text{erf}$ is the [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html) so that the one sided integral in $(e1)$ gives rise to this double sided alternating sum

$$s = \frac{\pi}{2 e^{\frac{1}{4}}}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^k \text{erfi}(\frac{1}{2} + i \pi k)\tag{e4}$$

It can also be written as

$$s = \frac{\pi}{2 e^{\frac{1}{4}}} \text{erfi}(\frac{1}{2} )+\frac{\pi}{e^{\frac{1}{4}}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \Re\left( \text{erfi}(\frac{1}{2} + i \pi k)\right)\tag{e5}$$

The asymptotic behaviour of the summand for $k\to \infty$ is given by

$$\frac{\pi}{2 e^{\frac{1}{4}}}\Re\left( \text{erfi}(\frac{1}{2} + i \pi k)\right)\sim \frac{e^{-\pi ^2 k^2} \sin (\pi  k)}{\pi ^{1/2} k}+O(\frac{1}{k^2})\tag{e6}$$

this shows the excellent convergence of the sum.

**Using Cauchy's theorem. Useful or not?**

In a (desparate) attempt to find a closed expression we could write both two-sided sums $(e1)$ and $(e4)$ in the form a contour integral with the kernel $\pi \cot(\pi n)$ and $\frac{\pi}{ \sin(\pi k)}$, repectively, but I see no use in it as both integrands diverge for large imaginary argument. Maybe someone else can pusue this approach?

**EDIT 29.06.18 13:15**

Correction

The previously provided closed expression $s_{c}$ was shown to be incorrect by some commenters.

As Mariusz pointed out correctly there are jumps in the function $p(z)$ (see (d8)) at $z=k \;\pi$

Correcting for $m$ of those jumps the closed expression is given by the (extremely fast converging) series

$$s_{c}(m) = s_{c}+\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt[4]{e}} \sum _{k=1}^m (-1)^k \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}+i \pi  k\right)+\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}-i \pi  k\right)\right)$$

*Numerical examples*

Letting $sN(100) = s$ up to 100 valid digits we obtain for the differences $d(m) = s_{c}(m) - sN(100)$ for $m=0..3$ the following

$$ \left\{-\frac{3.996}{10^6},-\frac{1.54}{10^{19}},-\frac{2.5929}{10^{41}},-\frac{1.456}{10^{71}}\right\}$$

Summarizing: instead of a true closed expression for $s$ we have effectively transformed one sum into another sum, which, however converges very fast.

The original question is now to be repeated for the latter sum.

*Remark*

Independently of this correction, the discovered strange numerical behaviour Mathematica deserves further study.

Note added 1. July: Some steps have already been taken here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176240/bug-in-analytical-expression-of-integral-containing-abs-function/176342#176342

**EDIT 28.06.18 14:00**

Doubts have been raised in comments that my result might be wrong. The arguments given seem to rely on the numerical evaluation in Mathematica. Therefore I have extended the derivation to show more steps so that possible flaws can be detected.

**Post as of 27.06.18**

I have found the closed expression for the sum

$$s=\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\exp \left(-n^2\right)}{1-4 n^2}$$

It is given by

$$s_{c}=\frac{\pi\;  \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt[4]{e}} $$

Derivation see below.

Numerically, the first 60 digits of $s_{c}$ according to Mathematica 10.1 are

$$N(s_{c}) = 0.75229|3902402569849043685417920199342618157039554017947019766$$

while, as has been pointed out in two comments, $s_{c}$ differs from $s$ numerically already in the fifth decimal digit:

$$N(s) = 0.75229|7898472243144830594123416216568518483359108518774883675$$

Something is wrong here.

**Original post**

As a partly solution we give here an integral representation of the sum in question

$$s=\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\exp \left(-n^2\right)}{1-4 n^2}$$

Splitting the sum into the term with $n=0$ and observing the symmetry of the summands $s$ can be witten as

$$s = 1-2 p\tag{1}$$

where

$$p = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\exp \left(-n^2\right)}{4 n^2-1}\tag{2}$$

Writing the denomintor for $n \ge 1$ as an integral

$$\frac{1}{4 n^2-1} = \int_0^{\infty } \exp \left(-t \left(4 n^2-1\right) \right) \, dt \tag{3}$$

leads under the integral to the sum

$$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \exp \left(-\left(4 n^2-1\right) t-n^2\right) $$

Which can be evaluated in terms of the Jacobi Theta function:

$$\frac{1}{2} e^t \left(\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-4 t-1}\right)-1\right)\tag{4}$$

Using (3) we find the integral representation

$$p=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} e^t \left(\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-4 t-1}\right)-1\right) \, dt\tag{5}$$

**Derivation of the closed expression**

The ingredients are easy to verify:

Partial fraction decomposition gives instead of (3):

$$\frac{1}{4 n^2-1} = \int_0^{\infty } \sinh (t) \exp (-2 n t) \, dt\tag{d1}$$

Under the Fourier transform the exponent becomes linear in $n$

$$e^{-n^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \exp \left(-x^2\right) \exp (2 i n x) \, dx\tag{d2}$$

Under the two integrals the sum for $p$ is linear in the Exponent, i.e. it is a geometric sum, and hence can easily be done:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \exp \left(-x^2\right) \sinh (t) \exp (-2 n t) \exp (2 i n x) = \frac{e^{-x^2+2 i x} \sinh (t)}{\sqrt{\pi } \left(e^{2 t}-e^{2 i x}\right)}\tag{d3}$$

Now the t-integral is solved by Matematica assuming that $x$ is real to give

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-x^2+2 i x} \sinh (t)}{\sqrt{\pi } \left(e^{2 t}-e^{2 i x}\right)} \, dt = \frac{e^{-x^2} \left(1+2 i \sin (x) \tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}\tag{d4}$$

Last but not least, the x-integral between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ can be written, using the symmetry of the integrand as

$$p=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-x^2} \left(1-i \sin (x) \left(\tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{-i x}\right)-\tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }} \, dx\tag{d5}$$

Observing that

$$i \left(\tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{-i x}\right)-\tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi }{2} \; \text{sgn}(\sin (x))\tag{d6}$$

the x-integral becomes

$$p=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-x^2} \left(1-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \left| \sin (x)\right| \right) \, dx\tag{d7}$$

where we have returned to the symmetric form, correcting this by the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ in front

Mathematica refused to do this integral directly but it was successful with the finite integral, with some $z\gt 0$

$$p(z)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}\int_{-z }^{z} e^{-x^2} \left(1-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \left| \sin (x)\right| \right) \, dx$$

$$= \frac{1}{8} \left(4 \text{erf}(z)+\frac{\pi  \left(-2 \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}+i z\right)+\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}-i z\right)\right) \csc (z) \left| \sin (z)\right| \right)}{\sqrt[4]{e}}\right)\tag{d8}$$

Now the Limit $z\to\infty$ has to be taken. Again Mathematica refused but it did this asymtotic series expansion about $z=\infty$

$$\frac{i \sqrt{\pi } e^{-z^2-i z} \csc (z) \left| \sin (z)\right| }{8 z}-\frac{i \sqrt{\pi } e^{-z^2+i z} \csc (z) \left| \sin (z)\right| }{8 z}-\frac{\pi  \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{4 \sqrt[4]{e}}-\frac{e^{-z^2}}{2 \sqrt{\pi } z}+\frac{1}{2}\tag{d9}$$

Letting now $z\to\infty$ gives finally

$$p = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi  \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{4 \sqrt[4]{e}}\tag{d10}$$

and the intial sum becomes

$$s = 1 - 2 p = \frac{\pi  \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt[4]{e}}$$

Comment: nice and interesting answer (+1)!

Comment: it was already very interesting in the first version, now it is super; but pls. elucidate better the steps leading to the new integral and to erfi

Comment: @ G Cab. Done, see section "derivation"

Comment: Probably I'm wrong,but yours closed expression is correct only with 5 digits?MMA code:`1 - 2 NSum[Exp[-n^2]/(4 n^2 - 1), {n, 1, Infinity}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 30]` $1-2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\exp \left(-n^2\right)}{4 n^2-1}=0.75229\color{red}{7898472243144830594123416}$

Comment: Or better one: `N[1 - 2 Sum[Exp[-n^2]/(4 n^2 - 1), {n, 1, 10}], 30]`

Comment: Yes you are right ,The given closed form is not correct

Comment: @ zeraoulia rafik What makes you sure that my expression is incorrect?

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk You seem to be judging from the numeric result. These differences might be due to Mathematica. I shall extend my Derivation so you can check if there's some flaw in it.

Comment: "These differences might be due to Mathematica": are you kidding ?

Comment: @ Yves Daust I have more than 10.000 reputation in Mathematica and have seen quite a lot of critical situations there over the years. I would appreciate if you join the search for the flaw in my derivation which in turn relies appreciably on Mathematica.

Comment: It's easy to check this using another code. For example SciPy in Python gives $s_c = 0.7522939024025698$  and $s = 0.7522978984722432$ which is in perfect agreement with Mathematica. ( Code: import numpy as np; from scipy.special import erf;  from numpy import complex; erfi = lambda z: complex(0.0, -1.0)*erf(complex(0.0, 1.0)*z); z = complex(0.5,0.0); erfi(z)/np.exp(0.25)/2.*np.pi )

Comment: Here is the source of the error in mathematica. Define a = 1 - 2 NIntegrate[1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) Exp[-x^2] (1 - 1/2 \[Pi] Abs[Sin[x]]), {x, -zmax, zmax}];  and  b = 1 - 2 Integrate[1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) Exp[-x^2] (1 - 1/2 \[Pi] Abs[Sin[x]]), {x, -z, z}]; By definition we should a=b when z=zmax, but N[a - b /. z -> zmax] evaluates to $\sim 4\cdot 10^{-6}$ for zmax $= 50$ (the difference between your result and the true sum.

Comment: The difference between these two expressions happens only for $z >\pi$. Thus it's probably a condition in the analytical expression that it only holds for $z<\pi$ that mathematica fails to list. (In the code above compare zmax=3+1/10+4/100 to zmax=3+1/10+5/100). If I were to guess it's likely due to the Abs[] function.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. Maple `2018.1` Sum numeric says:$0.75229\color{blue}{7898472243144}$. Ok. I'm not a mathematician, I can't solve this sum analytically but the evidence says that I'm right by: `99.999999999999%`.

Comment: Flaw is `d10` taking $z\to \infty$.Indefine integral `d7` have discontinuous in points $\pi  n$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ Winther Thanks for speaking of an error in Mathematica and pointing out the "watershed" of $z =\pi$. Do you think that (d7) is correct (i.e. 1-2p(d7) = s)? Could you check this numerically in another CAS?

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk Thanks for your remarks. Could you please check if (d7) is correct (i.e. 1-2p(d7) = s) numerically in Maple?

Comment: @ Winther Continuing your test I found (a) no error if the Exp-factor is dropped. Hence the Abs alone is ok (b) no error if the integral is taken one-sided (0..z). There is no warning issued by Mathematica that the result may be possibly wrong e.g. for zmax = pi+0.1. Taken together his strongly confirms my suspicion that something is wrong with Mathematica (Versions 10.1 and 8.0) in this case. I guess I shall report this in PSE Mathematica.

Comment: Define Integral $(d7)$ is correct. Maple says:`1-evalf(Int(exp(-x^2)*(1-(1/2)*Pi*abs(sin(x))), x = -infinity .. infinity, method = _Gquad, digits = 30))/sqrt(Pi)=0.752297898472243144830594123416`.I tired find symbolic solution,but Maple FAIL.

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk Thank you twice. It is gratifying that d7 correctly represents the $s$. Taking into account your remarks on discontinuity I have now provided a correct formula (see my answer).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze, I have showed your Answer to Cornel loan  he said me that's not correct , Really i didn't know if the titled problem proposed by Cornel loan valeen ( Romania)

Comment: @ zeraoulia rafik Ths is the second occasion here that Cornel Iona valeen is mentioned as the "authority in the background". Could you please ask him to reveal his knowledge? I would greatly appreciate learning more.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze,
your solution is very interesting for me. I'm working on a general method for such topics and I guess you just found the 
"right hand side" of a functional equation similar to the theta functions, which obey's the Poisson Summation Formula. I have another 
integral which is described by the sum over a Dawson-function, which  may be transformed to a more convergent sum over Error function. 
Is the post the current status of the problem, or have you made any progress with the solution in the meantime?

Comment: @ stocha Thank you for your kind remarks. No I haven't pursued this problem any further. Your approach sounds interesting. Did you take a look at the solution of Mariusz Iwaniuk?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: Yes. I will take some more time to work on the other method, post it and will send the link for your interest. Thanks!

Comment: I just finished the derivation. I got the exakt same result as Mariusz Iwaniuk. For this I just 
have to perform the Laplace-Transform on the sum, replace the $Coth$-Term by the asymptotic expansion and 
do the Inverse Laplace-Transform. The result is the right hand side of the functional equation for the 
"new theta function", obeying the Poisson Summation Formula. The sum ist equal to 
$$\sqrt{\pi } \,\text{DawsonF}\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]+\wp$$
where  the new constant  is defined by the infinite sum over the two imaginary error functions

Comment: @ stocha Very good. And thanks for inspiring me some days ago to find a simple derivation. See my recent EDIT.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: Thanks, too!

Answer (score 3):

I found general formula. It's not closed form solution only approximation for the sum:

$$\sum _{j=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\exp \left(-j^2\right)}{1-4 j^2}\approx \frac{\pi  \sum _{k=1}^n \left({\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}+(-1)^k
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}-k i \pi \right)+(-1)^k \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}+k i \pi \right)\right)}{2 \sqrt[4]{e}}$$

for $n=1$ it's only correct for 18 digits.

for $n=2$ it's only correct for 40 digits.

for $n=3$ it's only correct for 70 digits.

for $n=4$ it's only correct for 109 digits.

if $n>4$ then it's  better approximation and more correct digits.

**Derivation of the formula**

Borrowing integral $(d7)$ form [user Dr. Wolfgang Hintze](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/198592/dr-wolfgang-hintze) and integrating with Mathematica help:

$$\int \frac{\exp \left(-x^2\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \left| \sin (x)\right| \right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} \, dx=\\\frac{4 \sqrt[4]{e} \text{erf}(x)-\pi  \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}-i x\right)+\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}+i x\right)\right)+2 \pi 
   \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}-i x\right)+\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}+i x\right)\right) \theta (\sin (x))}{16 \sqrt[4]{e}}+C$$

taking limit in jumps points:

$$\left(\underset{x\to \pi ^-}{\text{lim}}\text{int}-\underset{x\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\text{int}\right)+\left(\underset{x\to \infty
   }{\text{lim}}\text{int}-\underset{x\to (2 \pi )^+}{\text{lim}}\text{int}\right)+\left(\underset{x\to (2 \pi )^-}{\text{lim}}\text{int}-\underset{x\to \pi
   ^+}{\text{lim}}\text{int}\right)+\left(\underset{x\to (-2 \pi )^-}{\text{lim}}\text{int}-\underset{x\to -\infty
   }{\text{lim}}\text{int}\right)+\left(\underset{x\to 0^-}{\text{lim}}\text{int}-\underset{x\to (-\pi )^+}{\text{lim}}\text{int}\right)+\left(\underset{x\to
   (-\pi )^-}{\text{lim}}\text{int}-\underset{x\to (-2 \pi )^+}{\text{lim}}\text{int}\right)=\\\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi 
   \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}-i \pi \right)-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}+i \pi
   \right)+\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}-2 i \pi \right)+\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}+2 i \pi \right)\right)}{4 \sqrt[4]{e}}$$

based on this, it was possible to deduce the formula.

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk  I saw your contribution only a few minutes ago. Sorry, was so busy creating my corrected solution. So we have arived independently at the same result. Still in my opinion, Mathematica is buggy with the finite integral, d7: it generates spurious jumps, without warning. Integrating a continuous function must not lead to jumps.  No, it is the ancient story that a finite integral can be wrong if the antiderivative has jumps ... But just returning a value for a finite integral without warning even if the antiderivative has jumps can be heavily miseading. What do you think?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. You may be interested:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176240/bug-in-analytical-expression-of-integral-containing-abs-function  People make mistakes, it is natural.Yes MMA  is buggy I'm sure of it. Over 2 years I sent them  to support over 250 bugs. Maple is not better either.About:antiderivative,jumps,well, it is probably difficult to implement 
for different cases.
We only hope that there will be as few bugs as possible.

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk Thanks for the link which the author himself didn't bother to tell us here. He takes the problem from my (painful) solution without mentioning the source :-( And we still don't know the answer to the original question ...

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk There seems to be a typo in your main formula. Shouldn't the denominator of $erfi(\frac{1}{2})$ be 1 rather than $n$?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze.Yes you are right.I edit my answer.